# Specific consecutive characters zero or more times ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Attempting to use `gsub` in order to convert the proceeding sequential consent characters of string as well as the combination of the characters `'qu'`.  How do I state via a regular expression `((two specific character in a specific order) OR (any character in a set of characters)) any number of times`

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
"stupid".gsub( /([(qu)]*[^aeiou]*)(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' #=> "upidstay" correct!
"uce".gsub( /([(qu)]*[^aeiou]*)(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' #=> "eucay" NOT correct :(

"stupid".gsub( /((qu)*[^aeiou]*)(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' #=> "stay" 

"uce".gsub( /([(qu)|[^aeiou]]*)(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' #=> "eucay" # why does just a "u" match?
```

I think what it comes down to is I don't know how to make multiple specific consecutive characters an option in `[]`, I thought it was `[(qu)]` but why does just a `u` get matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
cons = "(?:qu|[^aeiou])"
"uce".gsub(/^(#{cons}+)(.*)/,'\2\1') + 'ay' # => uceay
"stupid".gsub(/^(#{cons}+)(.*)/,'\2\1') + 'ay' # => upidstay
"quduck".gsub(/^(#{cons}+)(.*)/,'\2\1') + 'ay' # => uckquday
```

Comment: In that case you need to add "qu" to the list of consonants, using a non capturing group:
`cons = "(?:qu|[^aeiou])"`

Comment: `cons = "(?:qu|[^aeiou])"` does _not_ work as it fails to match characters in the string `"rququrqucebs".gsub( /(?:qu|[^aeiou])+(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' # => "ebsay"`

Comment: Of course it fails, you typed it wrong (forgot a pair of parenthesis):
`"rququrqucebs".gsub(/^((?:qu|[^aeiou])+)(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' => "ebsrququrqucay""`

Comment: I understand `^` is used to invert character properties but I'm having a hard time understanding why it would be necessary to invert `((?:qu|[^aeiou])+)`?  Could you briefly explain this so I might better understand what is happening?

Comment: Why would `"apple".gsub(/((?:qu|[^aeiou])+)(.*)/, '\2\1') # => "aeppl"`?

Comment: So, `^` inside `[]` inverts the selection, but without `[]`, `^` is an anchor meaning "starts with". You can find more info here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html
And it IS needed in this regex, otherwise it will just take all the consonants and add them to the end, (hence your apple example)

Answer (score 1):

A character class `[]` specifies characters to match so `[(qu)]` would match `(`, `q`, `u` and `)`

*Piglatin* RegEx: `/((?:(?:qu))*[^aeiou]*)(\w*)/`

Replace with: `'\2\1'` and append an `'ay'`

Code:

```
"quick".gsub( /((?:(?:qu))*[^aeiou]*)(\w*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay'
```

See example [here](http://regex101.com/r/jH5eF6).

Comment: That would append two 'ay'

Comment: @rudolph9: i don't see how that could be... check here: http://regex101.com/r/wT1mD7 It would help to show us some examples of these exceptions and their correct expected result

Comment: Run it, it appends two 'ay'.  After fiddling with this I've found the following, which is very similar to what you posted (and if you update you question with a the proper answer I will accept) is what produces the desired result: `string.gsub( /((?:(?:qu))*[^aeiou]*)(.*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay'`

Comment: updated post with `(.*)` instead of `(\w*)`. btw: `\w` is the same as  the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Agreed... I was more concerned about the third question mark which throws warnings and the 'ay'.

Comment: sorry, missed that since creating the regex. also you might want to use the `(.*)` version for words containing a `-` or `'`

Comment: I looked at it again, still not correct! `"rqurcebs".gsub( /((?:(?:qu))*[^aeiou]*)(\w*)/, '\2\1') + 'ay' # => "urcebsrqay"`